# Quantmod for S&P500 doesn't get the me right data

Tags: r, yahoo-finance

I used the following code to get the S&P500 data from yahoo using the quantmod package but I am not getting the right index close values. Have no idea what data is it this pulling Someone else who answered another question used the same code for the same ticker and got the right data. I tried used "GSPC" as well but the adjusted close price doesn't make sense. See screenshot for reference. Any suggestions? Or anyone facing the same issue?

```
library(quantmod)
SPX <- getSymbols("^GSPC",auto.assign = FALSE, from = "1980-01-01")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks right to me:

```
pacman::p_load(quantmod) 

SPX <- getSymbols("^GSPC",auto.assign = FALSE, from = "1980-01-01")


tail(SPX)
```

> ```
>            GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
> 2017-09-13   2493.89   2498.37  2492.14    2498.37  3368050000       2498.37
> 2017-09-14   2494.56   2498.43  2491.35    2495.62  3414460000       2495.62
> 2017-09-15   2495.67   2500.23  2493.16    2500.23  4853170000       2500.23
> 2017-09-18   2502.51   2508.32  2499.92    2503.87  3194300000       2503.87
> 2017-09-19   2506.29   2507.84  2503.19    2506.65  3249100000       2506.65
> 2017-09-20   2506.84   2508.85  2496.67    2508.24  3530010000       2508.24
> ```

This matches what I see on [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC?ltr=1).

I think I see the problem though. You'll notice that the object open in your screenshot has a different name. `SNP500` rather than `SPX`. **It's a different object.**

That's why the prices are lower. That's always why we don't really use screenshots on Stack Overflow, at least not for R data frames.

Comment: You are right. I got the right dataset now. 

Beginner level follow up question though: I am fairly new on Stackoverflow. Can you tell me how did you display the tail of your dataset without using the image option?

Reply much appreciated.

Thank you.